# Pandas lookup values in one column based on list of values of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with and id and value columns.

```
df=
id    val
'a'    1
'b'    3
'c'    9
```

....

I have a list of (repeated) id values.

```
i_list=['a','a','a','b']
```

I need to map this list of (repeated) id values into the corresponding (repeated) value columns, using the dataframe pairs (id,val)

```
out_desired=[1,1,1,3]
```

Right now I am doing:

```
out_desired=[df[df.id==curr_id].val.values for curr_id in i_list ]
```

How to do this in a more efficient yet still concise way?

Answer (score 2):

If the `id`s are lexicigraphically sorted you can use [`Series.searchsorted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html):

```
df.loc[df['id'].searchsorted(i_list), 'val'].to_numpy().tolist()
[1, 1, 1, 3]
```

Or you could set `id` as index (works for non sorted `id` too):

```
df.set_index('id').loc[i_list, 'val'].to_numpy().tolist()
# [1, 1, 1, 3]
```

If the `id` column is not sorted, sort and then do as above for the first approach to work:

```
print(df)
  id  val
0  c    1
1  b    3
2  a    9

df_ = df.sort_values(['id'])
df_.loc[df_['id'].searchsorted(i_list), 'val'].to_numpy().tolist()
[1, 1, 1, 3]
```

Comment: The second approach might be faster @00__00__00 setting as index

Comment: I will leave the question open for a couple of days as other answers may also be useful

Comment: Have you checked if the second approach works faster? I think its simpler, and should be faster @00__00__00

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) as it seems to be faster for me.

```py
df = {'id': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'value': [1,3,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df).set_index('id')
test = ['a', 'b', 'c']*8
```

```
%timeit df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'id':test}), left_index=True, right_on='id', how='right')['value'].values
1.32 ms ± 33.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit [df[df.index==curr_id].values for curr_id in test ]
5.81 ms ± 123 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I believe it gives the right answer